# How can I trigger a WiFi passwords restore?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, restore

I know that when you first setup a new phone you can choose to restore your WiFi passwords and installed apps from your Google account. I've even tried that a few times and it sure works. However this time for some reasons it didn't restore anything. The checkbox for restoring them is checked, but nothing is restoring.

Is there a way to manually triggering this restore process? It would suck if I'd have to retype all the passwords one by one, by hand.

Comment: You **are** connected via 4G or some other non-WiFi network, correct? Also, did you enable backups first?

Comment: @JoeSewell I'm connected to the internet via WiFi. Also I did enable backup.